# Create new list with condition of values (sublist) ​from another list in R

Tags: r, list

I have the list `ListResiduals` that looks like this:

```
ListResiduals
    OptionA   Value
          1       4
          2       0
          3       7
    OptionB   Value
          1       2
          2       2
          3       9
    OptionC   Value
          1       3
          2       2
          3       1
```

I need create a new list `Watchlist` with the names of the previous list where the last value is for example > 5, something like:

```
Watchlist
  OptionA 
  OptionB
```

I have the following code but it is creating a meaningless matrix for what I want.

```
    Watchlist <- sapply(ListResiduals, function(x) {
  (lapply(ListResiduals, tail, n = 1) > 5)
  })
```

Comment: Is `ListResiduals` as dataframe or a list? Can you provide `dput(ListResiduals)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
unlist(lapply(ListResiduals,
       FUN = function(d) names(d)[1][tail(d, 1)$Value > 5]))

# "OptionA" "OptionB"
```

`tail(d, 1)$Value > 5` checks if the last value of `Value` is `> 5`. We then select the first name of the data.frame (`OptionA`, `OptionB`, `OptionC`), but only keep that value if `tail(d, 1)$Value > 5` is `TRUE`

Using `unlist` will return a character vector.

#### Data

```
ListResiduals <- 
  list(d1 = data.frame(OptionA = 1:3, Value = c(4, 0, 7)),
       d2 = data.frame(OptionB = 1:3, Value = c(2, 2, 9)),
       d3 = data.frame(OptionC = 1:3, Value = c(3, 2, 1)))
```

Comment: Error in tail(d, 1)$Value : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Solved it with the following code:
`Watchlist <- as.list(unlist(lapply(ListResiduals,
              FUN = function(d) names(d)[1][tail(d, 1) > 5])))`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try

- `sapply` + `ifelse` + `na.omit`

```
> na.omit(sapply(ListResiduals, function(x) ifelse(tail(x, 1)$Value > 5, names(x)[1], NA)))
[1] "OptionA" "OptionB"
```

- `Filter` + `sapply`

```
> names(sapply(Filter(function(x) tail(x, 1)$Value > 5, ListResiduals), `[`, 1))
[1] "OptionA" "OptionB"
```

**Data**

```
> dput(ListResiduals)
list(structure(list(OptionA = 1:3, Value = c(4, 0, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(OptionB = 1:3, Value = c(2, 2, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L)), structure(list(OptionC = 1:3, Value = c(3, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`, `filter`, and `discard`:

```
library(purrr)

map(ListResiduals, function(df) filter(df, last(Value) > 5)) %>% discard(~!nrow(.))
```

*Used @bouncyball's `ListResiduals` (thank you)